# A generic error occurred in GDI+ - permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, gdi+, virtual-directory

When I attempt to save an image file to a virtual directory I get "A generic error occurred in GDI+."  This seems to be a permission issue, because during the debug process, I changed the file path to my local hard drive and was able to save the file.

The virtual directory is running under a specific domain account, with full control  given to the folder and the share. IIS is serving the images, and I can navigate through the directory structure of the virtual directory in IIS, and also save, rename and delete files in the folder while connected as the domain account.

When I attempt to save the file from the application, does IIS connect as some other user, other than me or the domain account?

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling we found a blog post by [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/2153.aspx) which fixed the problem.  To determine the account that the application in running under we used <%= Environment.UserName %> - this returned ASPNET (IIS 5.1 - does not have appPools)

We then added a username and password to the machine.config so the app would run under an account that we specified and not the ASPNET account

C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: or for later .net framework versions the account the app would run under would be: IIS APPPOOL\{apppool name here}